# iPad Safari mobile seems to ignore z-indexing position for object elements

Tags: html, ios, ipad, safari

I got a object element on a page that's working fine both in safari mobile and desktop. I have a seme-transparent pull-down menu that's working fine. The problem is, when the menu is under the object element on the ipad safari, on the desktop safari i can see the object under the menu (as desired), while on the mobile version the object element stay on the behind (ugly) no matter what i tell the css. Is there any workaround?
I want to the object element under the menu on  the ipad safari.

HTML (from the comment below)

```
<object width="530" height="320">
    <param name="movie" value="youtube.com/v/aXSL0MZAdiM&amp;vq=hd720">;
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="1">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="youtube.com/v/aXSL0MZAdiM&amp;vq=hd720"; type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="1" autostart="true" wmode="transparent" height="320" width="530">
</object>
```

Comment: Please provide your html & css code for us to help

Comment: <object width="530" height="320">  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/aXSL0MZAdiM&amp;vq=hd720">  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="1">  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/aXSL0MZAdiM&amp;vq=hd720" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="1" autostart="true" wmode="transparent" height="320" width="530"></object>

Comment: Ricky, I have edited your answer so it includes the code. There are some semicolons in weird places, not sure if this may be a cause of your problems...

Comment: Sorry .These semicolons are my fault. But  i sure this is not a cause of my problems